# ios - UITabBar images are not rendering on the emulator

Tags: ios, ios5, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbar, uitabbaritem

I have an image that looks like this:

[image]

I am trying to make it render on the UITabBar and here is what I did.   I went in XCode to File --> Add Files to Project, then I chose the files I wanted and they got added.

Then when I clicked on the files, on the right side of the screen, under "target membership" the checkbox was checked.

But when I added the file name to the UITabBar item, the emulator showed a blank rectangle instead of just empty space...so it recognized the image...but it didn't render that image.

Would someone happen to know what I did wrong? Are the dimensions of the image supposed to be rectangle or square? I have 48x48 square png file.

Comment: The tabbar should accept both square and rectangle images. What's the image filename, are you using both standard and @2x images? Have you tried any other images instead to see if they show up? If they do I would suspect there's something wrong with the image itself.

Comment: @Liam the image file name is house-48.png and I tried exactly that name and without the .png ....I am not sure what is the difference between the standard and 2x images - could you please explain what you mean?

Comment: I did try another image and I had the same thing happen where there is a placeholder rectangle that rendered, but not the actual image.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Can you check your image info?

These are the guidelines for UITabBar image:

- 30x30 (48x32)
- PNG
- Anti-aliased
- Transparency set

[Custom Icon and Image Creation Guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/IconsImages/IconsImages.html)

Comment: Anti-alising is technique of minimizing the distortion artifacts.

Comment: thank you, by the way, do the application icon and the launch icon also have to be anti-aliased?

Comment: it's not required but it's preferred